# php pdo code to pass selected value from listbox in sql query

Tags: php, pdo

I have a listbox. I need to pass selected value from listbox in Below sql query in where condition.

But this will happen only on selected value changed, because I don't have any button in my form and I want this without post, or without reloading the form.

How to pass only selected value in below query?

```
<select class="special-flexselect"  name="book"  onChange="showUser(this.value)">
    <option value="<?php if(isset($_GET['edit'])){ echo $data['book']; }?>"><?php 
    <option  value=""></option>
    <option  value="<?php echo $load_book["book_no"]; ?>"><?php echo $load_book["book_no"]; ?></option>
<?php }?>
</select>


<?php 
   $book = $database->getRows("SELECT DISTINCT receipt_no 
                               FROM scheme_master 
                               WHERE book_no = :book_no ", 
                                     array(':book_no '=>$book_no));  
    foreach($receipt as $row){ ?>
       "<?php echo $row['receipt_no']; ?>",
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I think you are talking about using AJAX, Thats too big an answer based on the fact you have not attempted anything like that in your example.

Comment: Also that code??? What a mess! Code neatly and your bugs will be more obvious. Also get rid of unnecessary `<?php` when you are already in a `<?php` block

Comment: sir i dont have enough knowledge of ajax...is it possible using javascript or any jquery...

Comment: Yes, AJAX stands for `asynchronous JavaScript and XML`

Comment: sit is it possible to get this value document.getElementById("city").value = data[i].cit;   and echo inside <script>
$(function() {
var availableTags = [

"red,gree",

];
function split( val ) {
return val.split( /,\s*/ );
}
function extractLast( term ) {
return split( term ).pop();
}</script>

Comment: i need to echo cit value  in place of red,gree,